# Mostrar y ocultar mensajes al validar campos de un modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, formularios

Estoy realizando algunas validaciones en dos campos que tengo en una ventana modal uno es `textarea` y el otro un `dropdownlist`.

El error sucede al momento de abrir la ventana modal me aparecen los mensajes de validación sin ni si quiera escribir o seleccionar algún dato en ellos, tampoco me aparece el mensaje en rojo tal como lo indica en las clases **CSS** que tengo creadas.

Lo que requiero es validar esos dos campos, el de comentarios que no se envié vació ni el dropdownlist sin que se seleccione algún dato de la lista.

```js
function validateAssigned() {
    valid = true;
    select = document.assignedModal
    textarea = document.assignedModal

    if (!textarea.descripcion.value || textarea.descripcion.value.length === 0) {
        textarea.descripcion.classList.add('invalid');
    } else {
        textarea.ticketNoteInput.classList.remove('invalid');
    }

    if (select.responsable.selectedIndex || select.responsable.selectedIndex.length === 0) {
        select.responsable.classList.add('invalid');
    } else {
        select.responsable.classList.remove('invalid');
    }


}
```

```css
select {
    display: block;
}

textarea {
    display: block;
}

select.validateable.invalid + .validation-message {
    display: block;
    color: red;
    font-size: 14px;
}

textarea.validateable.invalid + .validation-message {
    display: block;
    color: red;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form name="assignedModal" method="post" data-toggle="validator">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" >
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">
                    <span id="ticketTitle"></span>
                </h5>
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group" name="descripcion">
                    <label class="required-field" name="descripcion" form="Descripcion">Comentarios:</label>
                    <textarea onchange="validateAssigned(this)" id="ticketNoteInput" name="Note" class="form-control form-control-user validateable" rows="5"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="validation-message">
                    Campo requerido, ingrese los comentarios
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" id="AssignDiv" name="responsable">
                    <select onchange="validateAssigned(this)" id="asign" name="responsable" class="form-control form-control-user validateable" style="height: 50px; padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem; width: 100%;" tabindex="-1">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona una opción</option>
                        <option>Prueba 1</option>
                        <option>Prueba 2</option>
                        <option>Prueba 3</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="validation-message">
                        Campo requerido, seleccione una opcion
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                <button onclick="validateAssigned()" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <span type="buttonsave" class="fa fa-save"></span> Guardar
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que puedes mejorar tu código haciendo algunas correcciones:

- Para evitar que el textarea se envié vació o el dropdownlist sin seleccionar ningún elemento, puedes agregarles un `required`.
- Necesitas una clase para ocultar los mensajes y otra para mostrarlos, por defecto debe aplicarse la primera.
- Puedes tener otra clase que pinte de rojo los bordes de los elementos cuando no pasen la validación.
- Puedes emplear `document.getElementById()` para acceder a los elementos y `className` para cambiarles la clase por completo.

El código queda de la siguiente forma:

```js
function validateAssigned() {
    valid = true;
    select = document.getElementById('asign');
    textarea = document.getElementById('ticketNoteInput');

    if (!textarea.value || textarea.value.length === 0) {
        textarea.classList.add('invalid');
        document.getElementById('validation-message1').className="invalid-message";
    } else {
        textarea.classList.remove('invalid');
        document.getElementById('validation-message1').className="hide";
    }

    if (!select.value) {
        select.classList.add('invalid');
        document.getElementById('validation-message2').className="invalid-message";
    } else {
        select.classList.remove('invalid');
        document.getElementById('validation-message2').className="hide";
    }
}
```

```css
select {
    display: block;
}

textarea {
    display: block;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.invalid{
    border-color: #f55 !important;
}

.invalid-message {
    display: block;
    color: red;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.hide{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form name="assignedModal" method="post" data-toggle="validator">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" >
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">
                    <span id="ticketTitle"></span>
                </h5>
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group" name="descripcion" >
                    <label class="required-field" name="descripcion" form="Descripcion">Comentarios:</label>
                    <textarea onchange="validateAssigned(this)" id="ticketNoteInput" name="Note" class="form-control form-control-user validateable" rows="5" required></textarea>
                    <div class="hide" id="validation-message1">
                        Campo requerido, ingrese los comentarios
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" id="AssignDiv" name="responsable">
                    <select id="asign" onchange="validateAssigned(this)" name="responsable" class="form-control form-control-user validateable" style="height: 50px; padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem; width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona una opción</option>
                        <option>Prueba 1</option>
                        <option>Prueba 2</option>
                        <option>Prueba 3</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="hide" id="validation-message2">
                        Campo requerido, seleccione una opcion
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                <button onclick="validateAssigned()" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <span type="buttonsave" class="fa fa-save"></span> Guardar
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

de esa forma ya funciona como esperas, saludos.

Comment: Tienes idea de pronto de como hacer esta validación en el backend ?

Comment: @SebastianSalazar podría indicarte como hacerlo, imagino que lo quieres en C# y Asp.net, aunque mejor podrías preguntar en la pagina, otros usuarios tienen mas conocimiento sobre el tema.